# Android requestLocationUpdates stays on

Tags: android, gps

I have a serious issue. When calling the requestLocationUpdates function in Android, the GPS listens for a current position. But if the cell phone is indoors (say underground) then the GPS will continue to listen until a location is fixed.

This Kills my battery when testing... IS there any way to set to removeUpdates after 2 minutes of Listening for a position???

Thanks

Comment: If you are using an embedded MapView with a MyLocationOverlay, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10977854/1071942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my recommendation:

1. create a class that uses a Handler
2. use sendMessageDelayed to trigger the handler every 5 seconds
3. for the message.obj keep a counter of seconds and every time the handler is called increment the message.obj by 5.
4. when the message.obj reaches 120 then you know 2 minutes is up and you can use removeUpdate()
5. when onLocationChanged() is called then use removeMessages() on the handler and restart the sendMessageDelayed() with the object containing a 0

I *LOVE* handlers !!

Answer (score 3):

Add your own logic to call `removeUpdates()` after two minutes of not getting an update. There is no built-in timeout mechanism, but creating your own should not be especially hard.

Comment: The only timeout mechanism I can think of is to have an android service running in the background to deal with it after 2 minutes.. But that I think is highly inefficient. Thanks for the response, I bought your book, but I dont see anywhere about a efficient timeout mechanism..

Could you suggest one?? Thanks

Comment: @yuhistre: Without knowing what component is calling `requestLocationUpdates()` and what component is hosting the `LocationListener`, it is impossible to give you advice.