# GPS stays on using Intent call

Tags: android, gps, android-intent

I have a quick behavior question.  When I call the following lines of code:

```
String currURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+nLocation.getLatitude()+","+nLocation.getLongitude()+"&daddr=110+Possum+Hollow+Road,+Newark,+DE+19711+(Tri-State+Bird+Rescue)&hl=en&ll=AnotherLat,AnotherLong&spn=0.28323,0.683212&sll=AnotherLat,AnotherLong&sspn=0.283147,0.683212&geocode=FcejYQIdRnCE-w%3BFXn_XQIda4F8-yF_tbhhHBmAIw&vpsrc=0&mra=pd&z=11";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(currURL));
App.this.getParent().startActivity(browserIntent);
```

It seems to keep the GPS on.  Is there something wrong in what I was doing?

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you requested location updates, then you must do `removeUpdates(locationListener)`
So, right before doing `startActivity`, you might want to `removeUpdates`

Comment: Thanks so much!  I had forgotten to do that

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an embedded MapView with a MyLocationOverlay, you need to explicitly clean up/disable this resource using `MyLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation()`, when your MapView closes. Because these individual overlays request for a location for themselves, and this can leave the GPS unit switched on, with the GPS icon flashing in the Status Bar.

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/SmiBz--6COc/blu9Bhkrt1QJ